# why no command history in Java GUI for R (JGR)?

Tags: java, r

Apologies for asking in SO, but rforge.net doesn't seem to have either a forum or a working bugzilla.   Does anyone know if there's a functional reason that JGR doesn't allow saving and loading history?
If not, is there a way to submit a 'feature request' to the team?

Comment: rforge claims to have a bug / issue tracker, but it looks like you have to create an account to use it.  See http://r-forge.r-project.org/

Comment: As a general rule, questions of the form "why didn't they do it *this* way" are not objectively answerable, and tend to get closed as non-constructive.

Answer (score 0):

It quite possible that you need to read ?history. As the Details section of ?history says: "There are several history mechanisms available for the different R consoles, which work in similar but not identical ways. Other uses of R, in particular embedded uses, may have no history. The functions described here work under the readline command-line interface but may not otherwise (for example, in batch use or in an embedded application)." There are further details that may offer ways of correcting the problem in some instances.

Comment: I did verify that the JGR console maintains a history accessible via, e.g., up-arrow.  I sort of figured that anything existing during a session could be written/read if code were added to do so.  AFter all, any GUI which accepts commands can "collect" copies of these commands locally without having to depend on any R-internal mechanism.  Rstudio, so far as I can tell, does so.  The console puts out a message about loading history not being possible, but the Rstudio workspace reads .history and provides it locally.